# Получение подстроки в constexpr-функции

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, constexpr

Как написать constexpr-функцию, которая из строки возвращает произвольную подстроку?

Пусть, для упрощения, нужно получить первые 3 символа

```cpp
constexpr char * get_first_chars(const char * str, inc count) {
  .......
}

const char * get_first_chars("abcdef", 3);
```

Последние символы вернуть без проблем. А первые? Вставить в строку `\0` нельзя

Можно заменить `char*` на `std::string`, но `std::string` не разрешается использовать в constexpr-функциях

Comment: std::string_view пробовали?

Comment: @gdg сейчас на него смотрю. Озвученную проблему он решает, но мне бы еще конкатенацию добавить. Чтобы работало `get_first_chars("abcdef", 3) + "xyz"`

Comment: В 20 стандарте разрешается использовать `std::string` в `constexpr`. *Вставить в строку \0 нельзя* - ну так определитесь, чего вы хотите. Возвращать подстроку или делать новую c-style строку.

Comment: @user7860670 20 стандарт не позволяет использовать используемая библиотека. Конечная цель - облегчить логирование мне нужна конструкция `getClassName(__FUNCTION__) + '.trace'` `getClassName()` уже есть. Теперь хочу из нее сделать constexpr функцию

Comment: @AntonShchyrov - вам тогда придется колхозить некий ленивый конкатенатор-итератор, в который передавать два string_view, чтобы он их клеил прямо в тот момент, когда его попросят

Answer (score 0):

> Озвученную проблему [string_view] решает, но мне бы еще конкатенацию

Это делается примерно вот так:

```
constexpr std::size_t size = [&]{
    std::size_t size = 0;
    // Тут считаете size. Лямбда не обязательна, если можете без нее - убирайте.
    return size;
}();

constexpr std::array<char, size> str = []{
    std::array<char, size> str{};
    // Тут руками собираете строку в `str`.
    return str;
}();
```